# Problem with line height in FF5

Tags: firefox, css

I'm currently developing a site ( http://landscaping.jvsoftware.com/ ) but I'm having some strange problems in FF5 with the line heights, it just looks a bit bigger (like 0.1ems) in comparison to any of the other major browsers I don't remember having this problem before (or maybe I didn't notice it). I'm using the HTML5 Boilerplate Normalize CSS instead of a reset so I don't know if it has to do with this, do you guys know where the issue might be?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks a big bigger than what?

Comment: Sorry to not be clear enough, bigger compared to any of the other major browsers

Comment: If you set the `body{line-height:18px}` does it look the same to you? At the moment you are just multiplying default styles.

Comment: Yes, if I specify the units (like 1.5em) I get the same results, I thought when you left only the number it defaulted to ems thats why I left it like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could it be that FF5 is defaulting the `line-height` to a different measurement because for almost all of them you have `line-height:#;` without defining a measurement type(i.e em, px, or pt).

Comment: The problem persists even if I use the measurement type :(

Comment: Try looking at this link: http://www.blog.highub.com/css/css-hacks/firefox-css-line-height-problem/ and see if it solves your problem.